# Define method on activerecord relation

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to define a custom method on an activerecord relation, eg:

```
Transaction.all.summed_values
```

A simple example would be where `summed_values` should evaluate `sum(:value)` on the relation.

Where should I define the method `summed_values`? Looks like it should be on `ActiveRecord::Relation`. If it should be directly there, which file should I put it in?

Also, if this new method only has meaning for `Transaction`s, is there any way to tell rails to only define this method for `ActiveRecord::Relation`s that consist of `Transaction`s?

Comment: You can use directly `sum` on a Relation, like `Transaction.sum(:value)` provided by ActiveRecord::Calculations http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Calculations.html

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Create a `self.summed_values` method directly in the transaction model.

Comment: Tanzeeb: my apologies. Please edit your question and I will remove my downvote!

Comment: I did not understand that adding a class method to `Transaction` would work on the relation. Thanks!

Comment: please provide a definition

Comment: I just found out that using `class << self` is not the same as `def self.method_name`. (for anyone in the future reading this)

Comment: It works because CollectionProxy delegates unknown methods to the target of the Relation. See http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/CollectionProxy.html

Answer (score 6):

You should use extending

```
Transaction.all.extending do
  def summed_values
    sum(:what_you_want)
  end
end
```

For more info: [ActiveRecord::QueryMethods](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-extending)

Answer (score 1):

Is there any specific reason why you want to create this method as extension to ActiveRecord::Relation? I would propose a class method like so:

```
class Transaction ...
  def self.summed_values(transactions=nil)
    if transactions.nil?
      all.sum(...)...
    else
      where(id => transactions).sum(...)...
    end
  end
end
```

This also has the advantage that it is only available for transactions.

Comment: this doesn't read as cleanly or match my meaning as well as the solution I'm after. the method I want to call specifically has meaning on the relation object, both conceptually and in the implementation. I agree this would work, but it's not what I'm after.

Comment: I'm not sure why you would like it on ActiveRecord::Relation object and yet have it only apply to Transaction. The only logical approach would be to subclass Relation and have Transaction use your subclass instead, and I don't think that is cleaner by any means.

Comment: I did not understand previously how this worked, and didn't realize that you could add a class method to `Transaction` and it would work on the relation. Thanks for helping me understand...